# Symfony2 - User specific form based on role access

Tags: forms, symfony, drop-down-menu, user-roles

I have a form that has a category field drop down that has a (OneToMany/ManyToOne) to a post entity.

**Situation:** Right now the client has to select category in the drop down and they can make the mistake of selecting the wrong category and this will go to another blog (if they select the wrong one) and they will not have access to change this back to the proper category.

To alleviate this potential problem I'd like to do one of the two as a solution:

**1) Set the category automatically based on the category they have access to**

**2) Or restrict the user to only select the category they have access to (e.g., if the user has a specific role they only get this category for the drop down)**

The user has a ROLE_USER restriction that allows them to only CRUD what they have access to.

e.g.,

- ROLEUSER1 only has access to /category1 (and can use CRUD on this)
- ROLEUSER2 only has access to /category2 (and can use CRUD on this)
- ROLEUSER3 only has access to /category3 (and can use CRUD on this)

How can I set this up so the client cannot make the mistake of selecting the wrong category?

Form

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('title')
        ->add('body')
        ->add('author')
        ->add('category')
        ->add('file', 'file', array(
            'label'    => 'Image',
            'required' => false
        ))
        ->add('created');
}
```

Controller

```
public function job1CreateAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Post();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('job1_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    );
}

private function createCreateForm(Post $entity)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new PostType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('job1_create'),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

    return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this? :
remove 'category' field from form builder and manually set it in controller action:

```
if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLEUSER1') {
    $entity->setCategory(CATEGORY1);
}
```

EDIT:

controller action:

```
public function job1CreateAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Post();

    if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLEUSER1') {
        $category1 = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('MYBUNDLE:POST')->find(1); // we are getting category object. this is just an example cade, may be this will be different in your case

        $entity->setCategory($category1);
    }

    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    ....
}
```

and form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('title')
        ->add('body')
        ->add('author')
        //->add('category')
        ->add('file', 'file', array(
            'label'    => 'Image',
            'required' => false
        ))
        ->add('created');
}
```

Comment: Question with this approach, I am using the CRUD generation `doctrine:generate:crud`, so where does this go in the controller, can you show an example?

Comment: @chance if you generated actions with doctrine, you should look at your PostController in Controller folder. there must be createAction.. simply edit that action..

Comment: Right, but where in the createAction, updated my query to show the createAction and createForm action.

Comment: @chance i updated the answer, added some sample code

Comment: @chance find() method fetches the object by id, you can find some information [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database)